# Using windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" hiding actionbar and adjust resize shrinking layout

Tags: android

In a chat application,I have an activity with an image as its background.Now when i enter a message to post the keyboard of phone appears and make my layout shrink when i use windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in manifest file.Also when i use windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" phone keyboard hide action bar.These two problems are skillfully resolved in many apps thats in market today,for example whatsapp chat.Please help me to resolve this problem in my app.Below is the layout of my chat activity.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/chat_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="11"
    tools:context="com.sixsquarekik.app.ChatActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/setFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mlistView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >
            </ListView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_window_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mEditText1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:ems="10"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:hint="Message here"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/mButton"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:onClick="onSendMessage"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send_now"
                android:text="send" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you got any answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an xml bitmap and use it as background for the view. To prevent stretching you can specify `android:gravity` attribute.

for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/dvdr"
    android:tileMode="disabled" android:gravity="top" >
</bitmap>
```